# Where does tomcat keep the files it is instructed to read?

Tags: java, xml, windows, file, tomcat

I need some help here. It is redicolous, but my TomCat just does not take the file I want. I am trying to read some properties from a xml file. When I startup tomcat with the WAR file inside it makes a folder "MyApp".
My program points to MyApp\WebContent\myXmlFile.xml

It used to work fine, but i needed to edit the myXmlFile.xml so I did by adding two more properties, but it just doesnt read the new data. How is this even possible? I keep removing the "MyApp" folder from inside tomcat\webapps\ so it makes a new one, but it just keeps getting other data. My code is refreshed, but this file doesn't.

Some help would be appreciated a lot. 
I am running Tomcat 7

More detail:

The myXmlFile.xml is inside the WAR file. I am not modifying it in runtime. It is suppose to be some sort of a configuration file. It reads the file once everytime there is a call done to this function. It just reads the xml files and puts properties inside a string.

When i upload the WAR file. I will first use shutdown.bat, than I will use startup.bat when the WAR file is in webapps.

Comment: Is there a copy of "myXmlFile.xml" inside the WAR for this application? Are you modifying the copy of the file inside the WAR? Or just the copy in the WebContent directory? Are you restarting tomcat after editing the file? What  part of your application actually reads myXmlFile.xml? Does it read the file once when the application starts, or does it do something else? For example, does it re-read myXmlFile.xml every time it reads data from the file?

Comment: @Kenster I have editted my question.

Comment: Has no one had  this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Tomcat. In Linux, type

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat8 restart
```

Comment: shutting down and starting seems good enough. I haven't used the restart, but i geuss it is the same thing. This unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any other copy of this file with the old values in another folder. I would try to delete (or rename) myXmlFile.xml from the WAR and see what is generated in the Tomcat deploy folder.